# Perl script runs in terminal but doesn't run when invoked from Java program

Tags: java, perl, runtime.exec

I was running a Perl script that replaces a string with another:

```
perl -pi.back -e 's/str1/str2/g;' path/to/file1.txt
```

When I run this command from terminal it well replaces all the occurrences of `str1` in the given file to `str2`. When I run this from java it does access the file but no replacement occurs:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("perl -pi.back -e 's/str1/str2/g;' path/to/file1.txt");
```

- I'm sure it accesses the file (the file seems to be edited in gedit(reload required)).
- I tried Java `ProcessBuilder` class but the same result happens.
- When I use `Runtime.exec()` or `ProcessBuilder` with other commands (like `gedit newFile.txt`) they work well.
- Ironically, I printed the above perl command from java and take the paste in terminal and the replace operation is done!
- No exceptions or errors by using those commands. (I used try and catch to ensure this).
- I also used `/usr/bin/perl` instead of `perl` in the cmd to ensure the perl cmd is executed.

So what do you think the problem is?

EDIT:

I solved this problem by just removing the quotes from the command in java. Thanks to @ikegami for help.
So the working version is:

```
perl -pi.back -e s/str1/str2/g; path/to/file1.txt
```

instead of

```
perl -pi.back -e 's/str1/str2/g;' path/to/file1.txt
```

Comment: `exec()` returns you a `Process`, it has `getInputStream()` and `getErrorStream()` methods which return you whatever output the process creates. See what this process outputs.

Comment: Depending on the OS, your Java program probably does not have the path to Perl. You'll  need to put the full path in to the Perl binary. That's not the only way to do it, but one of the simplest ways.

Comment: @DenisTulskiy I already did this. They output nothing.

Comment: @octopusgrabbus I did this but also same problem.

Comment: @ikegami I owe you one. Removing the quotes get it working! Thanks but I wanna ask why should I remove the quotes?

Comment: What's the difference between the shell commands `echo "foo's"` and `echo foo\'s`? None whatsoever. Both pass `foo's` to `echo`.

Comment: What I am suggesting is that you print your PATH in both instances. From the command line, it's simple. From the program, you'll need to get env from a Java --> sys-exec routine and print the PATH that way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`exec` uses `StringTokenizer` to parse the command, which apparently just splits on whitespace.

Take for example the following shell command (similar but different than yours):

```
perl -pi.back -e 's/a/b/g; s/c/d/g;' path/to/file1.txt
```

For it, `StringTokenizer` produces the following command and arguments:

- `perl` (command)
- `-pi.back`
- `-e`
- `'s/a/b/g;`
- `s/c/d/g;'`
- `path/to/file1.txt`

That's completely wrong. The command and arguments should be

- `perl` (command)
- `-pi.back`
- `-e`
- `s/a/b/g; s/c/d/g;` (Note the lack of quotes.)
- `path/to/file1.txt`

You could pass those above to `exec(String[] cmdarray)`. Or if you don't have the option of parsing the command, you could actually invoke a shell to parse it for you by passing the following to `exec(String[] cmdarray)`:

- `sh` (command)
- `-c`
- `perl -pi.back -e 's/a/b/g; s/c/d/g;' path/to/file1.txt`

Comment: You should try `perl -le'print for @ARGV' perl -pi.back -e 's/str1/str2/g;' path/to/file1.txt` and see what is actually passed to Perl by the shell. You should also try it without the (unnecessary) space after the `-e`.